# connect to cloudera kafka cluster using kafka connect in redhat client machine

Tags: apache-kafka, kerberos, apache-kafka-connect

I have to connect to cloudera kafka cluster using kafka connect

kafka cluster apache version => 0.11
cloudera vrsion =  cdk 3.1

cloudera cluster is secured with Kerberos
I am able to connect where kafka connect client in centos 7

I am not able to connect where kafka connect client in redhat 8

Error as below

```
[2021-05-25 04:54:56,855] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -2 (xxxxxxxx:9092) terminated during authentication. This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:769)
```

cloudera cluster ssl not enabled , runs on 9092 port

then i tried console producer as well , that also gave below error with redhat8 only

```
[2021-05-29 09:16:31,772] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -4 (xxxxk4.domain/xx.xxx.xx.47:9092) terminated during authentication. This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2021-05-29 09:16:31,772] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker xxxxk4.domain:9092 (id: -4 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2021-05-29 09:16:31,895] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 (xxxxk1.domain/xx.xxx.xx.44:9092) terminated during authentication. This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

jaas file for console producer as below

```
KafkaClient {
        com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
        useKeyTab=true
        storeKey=true
        keyTab="/home/test/keytabs/username.keytab"
        principal="user1@DOMAIN.DOMAINaABC.COM";
};
```

client.property  file as below

```
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka
```

kafka connect property file as below

```
consumer.security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
coonsumer.sasl.jaas.config=com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required \
   useKeyTab=true \
   storeKey=true \
   keyTab="/home/test/keytabs/user.keytab" \
   principal="username@DOMAIN.XXXXXABC.COM";
```

how we tried

`bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties default-connectortest.properties`

console command as below

```
 sh kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list namek1.domain.lk:9092,xxxxk2.xx.company.lk:9092, --producer.config /opt/analytics/xxxx/client.properties --topic sample --property print.key=true --property key.separator=" -> "
```

```
cat /etc/krb5.conf
# Other applications require this directory to perform krb5 configuration.
includedir /etc/krb5.conf.d/

[libdefaults]
default_realm = DOMAIN.NAME1ABC.COM
dns_lookup_kdc = true
dns_lookup_realm = false
ticket_lifetime = 86400
renew_lifetime = 604800
forwardable = true
default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts
default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts
permitted_enctypes = aes256-cts
udp_preference_limit = 1
kdc_timeout = 9000
ignore_acceptor_hostname = true
[realms]
NAME1.NAME1ABC.COM = {
kdc = name.DOMAIN.NAME1ABC.COM
admin_server = name2.name1.nameabc.com
}
```

Comment: Please show your connect-standalone.properties

Comment: Perhaps you can try to add `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true` to your `KAFKA_OPTS` to get some clues re. why it is failing. Also, what is JRE/JDK version on the new RHEL nodes?